# I have tried to run following code in VS Code and got error message. Can someone explain what is wrong here?

Tags: python, numpy

VS Code Python:

```
import numpy as np
x =[1,2,3]
my_arr =np.asarray(x)
print(my_arr)
print(my_arr.dtype)
```

```
  Exception has occurred: AttributeError
    partially initialized module 'numpy' has no attribute 'asarray' (most likely due to a circular import)
    File "C:\Users\HP\Desktop\python\numpy.py", line 3, in <module>
    my_arr =np.asarray(x)
    File "C:\Users\HP\Desktop\python\import numpy as np.py", line 1, in <module>
    import numpy as np
```

Comment: Don't name your own file `numpy.py`.

Comment: Did you read the quality guidance before you submitted this question?